# Remove white space on right side of pgfplot

Tags: latex, margin, pgfplots

Currently I have the following figures (plots):

[image]

I have placed the pgfplots inside two subfigures such that I can add the captions. The problem however is that some white space is added on the right side of Figure 3b. I am using the \hfill option but still this white space is note removed. Does someone know how to get rid of this white space such that the righthandside of Figure 3b alligns with the borders of my paper (represented by text text text ...)

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{font=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={},
        xlabel={Epochs},
        ylabel={Rewards},
        ylabel near ticks,
        legend pos=south east,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=densely dotted,
        width=7cm,
        height=6cm,
        legend cell align={left},
        legend style={font=\footnotesize}
    ]
    \addplot[color = black, line width = 0.25mm, mark = *, mark size = 1] coordinates {
        (1, 1.5)(2, 1.3)
        };
    \addplot[color = black, line width = 0.25mm, mark = none, samples = 2, dashed] {1.4}; % Constant line
    \legend{Plot1,}
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
        ylabel={Percentage (\%)},
        axis y line*=right,
        ylabel near ticks,
        ylabel style={rotate=-180},
        hide x axis,
        width=7cm,
        height=6cm,
        legend style={font=\footnotesize}
    ]
    \addplot[color = black, mark = *, mark size = 1] coordinates {
    (1, 0.5)(2, 0.6)
    }; 
    \addplot[color = black, line width = 0.25mm, mark = none, samples = 2, dashed] {0.53}; % Constant line
    \legend{Plot2,}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Performance}
\label{Plot:}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={},
        xlabel={Epochs},
        ylabel={Rewards},
        ylabel near ticks,
        legend pos=south east,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=densely dotted,
        width=7cm,
        height=6cm,
        legend cell align={left},
        legend style={font=\footnotesize}
    ]
    \addplot[color = black, line width = 0.25mm, mark = *, mark size = 1] coordinates {
        (1, 1.5)(2, 1.3)
        };
    \addplot[color = black, line width = 0.25mm, mark = none, samples = 2, dashed] {1.4}; % Constant line
    \legend{Plot1,}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Action distribution}
\label{Plot:}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Results}
\label{Plot:}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre]?

Comment: I suspect that your 7 cm are not the same as .49\textwidth, but without the documentclass and packages, that's just a guess

Comment: Sure @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I have added the documentclass and packages

Comment: Did you test the document? It does not compile

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz strange it did compile when I tested it in overleaf, I changed a few packages, can you try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your plots are about 7 cm wide and you place them in a `subfigure` of `.49\textwidth`, so the `\hfill` you place between the `subfigure`s only sees the objects of `.49\textwidth` and add fill space according to this. If you want to move the plot towards the right boarder, you could

a) place the `\hfill` into the subfigure (the caption won't be centred anymore)

b) adjust the `.49\textwidth` to match the actual width of the plot (something around 7 cm)

(the `\fbox{...}` in the code below is just to visualize the size of the plots)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{font=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}

\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={},
        xlabel={Epochs},
        ylabel={Rewards},
        ylabel near ticks,
        legend pos=south east,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=densely dotted,
        width=7cm,
        height=6cm,
        legend cell align={left},
        legend style={font=\footnotesize}
    ]
    \addplot[color = black, line width = 0.25mm, mark = *, mark size = 1] coordinates {
        (1, 1.5)(2, 1.3)
        };
    \addplot[color = black, line width = 0.25mm, mark = none, samples = 2, dashed] {1.4}; % Constant line
    \legend{Plot1,}
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
        ylabel={Percentage (\%)},
        axis y line*=right,
        ylabel near ticks,
        ylabel style={rotate=-180},
        hide x axis,
        width=7cm,
        height=6cm,
        legend style={font=\footnotesize}
    ]
    \addplot[color = black, mark = *, mark size = 1] coordinates {
    (1, 0.5)(2, 0.6)
    }; 
    \addplot[color = black, line width = 0.25mm, mark = none, samples = 2, dashed] {0.53}; % Constant line
    \legend{Plot2,}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\caption{Performance}
\label{Plot:}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\hfill%
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={},
        xlabel={Epochs},
        ylabel={Rewards},
        ylabel near ticks,
        legend pos=south east,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=densely dotted,
        width=7cm,
        height=6cm,
        legend cell align={left},
        legend style={font=\footnotesize}
    ]
    \addplot[color = black, line width = 0.25mm, mark = *, mark size = 1] coordinates {
        (1, 1.5)(2, 1.3)
        };
    \addplot[color = black, line width = 0.25mm, mark = none, samples = 2, dashed] {1.4}; % Constant line
    \legend{Plot1,}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\caption{Action distribution}
\label{Plot:}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Results}
\label{Plot:}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```